# DBOwner to another SQL Server User

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

How can I change the owner of all the tables and stored procedures in an SQL Server 2000 Database.

I think "sp_changeobjectowner" can do it, but I can't find a way to achieve this.

can anyone help me ?

`EDIT`

```
declare
@old_owner char(45),
@new_owner char(45)

set @old_owner = 'dbo'
set @new_owner = 'mynewuser'

select 'exec sp_changeobjectowner ''' + replace(@old_owner,' ','') + '.' + t1.name + '''' + char(44) + char(32) + '' + @new_owner + '' + char(13) 
from sysobjects t1, sysusers t2
where t1.uid = t2.uid
and t1.name not like 'sys%'
and t2.uid <> 7
and t2.name = @old_owner
```

Comment: Ok... now what went wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong, but I still have dbo the owner of everything in my database.

Comment: Did you actually run the results that your select statement generated? You need to actually copy them, paste them back in the query window, then run them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you have will return a result set that has all of the commands that you will need, but you still need to actually run those commands.

Copy the results, paste them into a query window, and try running them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the new owner is a user in that database.

You may need to preface the user name with the domain name: 'domain\username'.

```
use Northwind 
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1="sp_changeobjectowner '?', 'domain\username'"
```

Or maybe try using a cursor if you need to only change owners based on some criteria:

```
DECLARE tables CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT [name]
      FROM sysobjects
     WHERE xtype = 'u'

OPEN tables
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(512)
FETCH NEXT FROM tables INTO @TableName

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC sp_changeobjectowner @TableName, 'dbo'

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE tables
DEALLOCATE tables
```